# Sync Framework download with filter and but upload all

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I want to synchronize data between central SQL server database and SQL Server Local DB. Most tables are download and upload without filter. One table should be downloaded by using a filter, but should be uploaded without filter. Are there any sample code for this situation? should I provision two different scopes in both server database and Local DB?

Answer (score 0):

just create separate scopes and you should be fine.

1 - Filtered Download Scope
2 - Unfiltered Upload Scope